# How can I convert an object array to string for searching purposes?

Tags: java, arrays, search

So I have an array which can be added to by the user through the console
When I attempt to `System.out.println(the array);`, this appears:

```
project.Artist@31efa79f
```

So obviously if the artist name was John 
and someone searched for John they wouldn't find it as it appears as
`project.Artist@31efa79f`
so how do I get the array to display and allow search for this as the user input?

How would I also go about searching the array for a particular artist using a scanner?
So the scanner would allow the user to enter the required artist name and then it would search the array to see if there was a match to that name?

Comment: `Arrays.toString(...)`?

Comment: Why would you *want* to do that? Say you convert the array to a string and find "John" in it. Then what? You don't know what entry it was in... Why not just loop through the array? After all, creating a string for the array will have to loop through it, you're not avoiding anything...

Comment: Use a `Collection`, like `java.util.ArrayList` rather than an array. You can do a lot more, very easily, with the right collection type.

Answer (score 0):

Use either:

- `Arrays.toString(myArray)` for single-dimension arrays, or
- `Arrays.deepToString(myArray)` for multiple-dimension arrays

Your custom objects will have to `@Override` the `Object#toString` method to print a human-readable representation.

You probably want to search by property value instead, though.

So, if your `MyObject` has a property `artistName`, you implement a getter for that property (`getArtistName`), then iterate a `Collection<MyObject>` until `getArtistName().equals("John")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write loop and iterate over all the elements and you can give response by comparing the elements of array.

and if you want to convert array in to String object then you can use

```
Arrays.toString(Object [] arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))** method of `Arrays class`, like this:

```
//If you have an object array obj
Arrays.toString(obj);
// returns a String containing the obj elements
```

Take a look at the [**Java.util.Arrays.toString(Object[]) Method**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_tostring_object.htm) for further information.